# DataStage SAP BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN

Tags: datastage, sap-erp, bapi

I'm trying to load some data via DataStage with the BAPI `BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN`.

I need the parameters `IT_METHODS` and `IT_HEADER`.

But I have a problem with the fields :

> T_IT_HEADER_BAPI_ALM_ORDER_HEADERS_I_BASICSTART and
> T_IT_HEADER_BAPI_ALM_ORDER_HEADERS_I_BASIC_FIN (numeric (6)).

I try to map 000000 or 100000 or '100000'... but I always have this error :

> BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN,0: Error: RFC Error: RFC_CONVERSION_FAILURE
> DSTAGE-BAPI-F-00096 : RFC Error: Cannot convert string value 100000

Do you have some idea?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

Those values don't make any sense, as 'BASICSTART' and 'BASIC_FIN' reference Basic OrderHeader Dates. The SAP-convension uses dates like 'YYYYMMDD', so you would / should have something like '20170310'.

Check the following :

- Documentation on the BAPI : [link](https://www.consolut.com/en/s/sap-ides-access/d/s/doc/F-BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN)
- Some sample code : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014747/sap-rfc-how-to-change-date-on-a-pm-order)

Kind regards

Nic T.